# What is the downside of having many inodes?

Tags: debian, inode

Too few inodes can result in you not being able to store anymore files. What is the the downside of having many inodes ? (more than default)

Comment: The only downside I see is more space will be reserved for inodes and as a result the actual space on the disk will be reduced.

Comment: By how much ? How does it work ? What does it look like ?

Answer (score 2):

Inodes reserve space on the disk that cannot be used for storing your data.  That is about the only issue.

Answer (score 1):

Any operation that scans the inode table will be slower.  This can affect fsck or other recovery functions.  Also, when the inode table is cached this can take up memory. [This answer may also provide insight](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21325/is-the-file-table-in-the-filesystem-or-in-memory)

Comment: I believe that the only inodes that are cached in memory are those that are active (open, in the process of being exec'ed, somebody's working directory, a mount point, etc.). A larger number of inodes allocated in the filesystem on disk should not affect the usage of the in-memory inode table.