# Is there a command to run an executable?

Tags: shell

`bash`enables to run bash scripts with `bash somescript`, `python` python scripts with `python3 somescript`. Alternatively, with the right shebang, I can run directly the previous scripts with `./somescript`.

For binary programs, I can run them as `./someprogram` if they have the executable permission set.

But is there a GNU/Linux command to run a binary executable, say *run*, like in: `run someprogram`?

Typical use case is: *someprogram* is in a partition with `noexec` set. Such *run* command would enable to run myprogram as if it were in the partition where *run* is installed as `usr/bin` which is mounted with the `exec` flag.

Remark: it is not a `chmod`issue. *someprogram* has the `exec` permission set.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83866/108618

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to chmod without /usr/bin/chmod?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83862/how-to-chmod-without-usr-bin-chmod)

Comment: None of your propositions work in my case.

Comment: The 1st comment link is about using the dynamic linker to execute any dynamically linked executable even without permission for execution. The *title* of the link is not to solve it. The solution is not about using chmod. Only the answer about ld.so (ld-linux ...). It won't work for statically linked executables though. What is yours? (`file ./binary`)

Comment: ok, thanks for the clarification. If I run `/lib/ld-linux.so.2  someprogram`, I get: `error while loading shared libraries, wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64`

Comment: @A.B and anyway, Linux won't allow ld-linux.so to mmap files as executable in the process memory if it's on a FS mounted with noexec, it would need to be copied with a FS without noexec.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, that ld.so approach won't work for files on a FS mounted with noexec.

Comment: @lalebarde, you'd likely need `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 someprogram` in your case, but even that won't work if the file is on a FS with noexec. noexec is especially to prevent the machine code from the file from being executed by the processor. You'd need to copy the file to a FS without noexec first.

Comment: @Stéphane, thank you very much. I moved it and have now other problems possibly for further questions. So the answer is no way to run a program located in a noexec volume.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for the information. Difficult to cheat the system

Comment: IIRC running the dynamic loader manually used to work even for non-executable files under older kernels. But you had to be able to read the file, and of course stuff like setuid didn't work.

Comment: @ilkkachu it still works for a non-executable binary on a standard ("exec") mount. But on a noexec mount it fails as Stéphane Chazelas wrote. One gets this error: `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /tmp/sleep 1` `/tmp/sleep: error while loading shared libraries: /tmp/sleep: failed to map segment from shared object`. This is documented in Linux' `mmap(2)` for one of the multiple causes of EPERM.

Comment: @Stéphane, if you set your answer, I will validate it, thanks again.

Comment: IIRC, someone once managed to write a `execve()` in user space, so it might be possible. I think I read it somewhere here, so there might be a Q&A covering it here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas this Q/A https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/725590/does-linux-support-invoking-a-program-directly-via-its-inode-number/725597#725597 has some references about it. Anyway such code has to be available in an place where it can be executed, even if it's to "execute" code in a place where it can't naturally be.